# Problems with mount cifs

Tags: linux, ubuntu, samba, cifs

It is a couple of days I'm struggling in mounting a samba shared directory in Ubuntu 16. I read all the relative posts but still cannot find a solution.

Here is the command I use:

```
e sudo mount -vt cifs -o username=sdea,sec=ntlmssp,vers=1.0 //130.226.50.5/sdea/ /home/sdea/jess
```

and the error i get:

```
mount.cifs kernel mount options: ip=130.226.50.5,unc=\\130.226.50.5\sdea,sec=ntlmssp,vers=1.0,user=sdea,pass=********
```

mount error(13): Permission denied

I can mount this directory on my Mac and on Ubuntu 14 (on another machine), without any sort of problem. So, I'm sure my credentials are right. I also tried to include different "sec" options like sec=nltm,nltmv2 etc.. but nothing. I always get permission denied.

The version of the cifs-utils installed is 6.3, the linux kernel is 4.13.0-26-generic. I don't have sudo privileges on the server, but the configuration should be right since I can mount the share on different machines.

Do some of you have some clue on what the problem could be?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Kernel 4.13 has introduced changes in SMB, Have a look at [Linux kernel 4.13 and SMB protocol version fun](https://www.happyassassin.net/2017/11/03/linux-kernel-4-13-and-smb-protocol-version-fun/) for mor info.

In my case, the only thing that worked was a [Kernel downgrade](http://karlcode.owtelse.com/blog/2017/03/13/reverting-to-a-previous-kernel/).

If I was you, I would try first to changing the **vers=1.0** to **vers=2.0** and/or **vers=3.0**

Comment: I indeed tried the different "vers" options. However, even for me, the only solution was a kernel downgrade. Thanks for your answer!